# How to insert data from 2 other tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm making a new table. The value/data in the table are taken from another table. for example: in `table A` I have field `Code` with 2 data, `EXE` and `IMP`. In `table B` I have field `Year` with data `2016` and `2017`. Now i need to make `table C` with field `Status` where the data in field `Status` are `EXE-2016`, `IMP-2016`, `EXE-2017` and `IMP-2017`. How was the query for this kind of problem?

```
table A
code | code_name | flag
EXE | Execute | Y
IMP | Implement| Y

table B
Year | phase | flag
2016 | P1 | Y
2016 | P2 | Y
2017 | P1 | Y
2017 | P2 | Y
2018 | P1 | N

table C
Status | Flag
EXE-2016 | Y
IMP-2016 | Y
EXE-2017 | Y
IMP-2017 | Y
EXE-2018 | N
IMP-2018 | N
```

Comment: HINT: `create table [table_1] as select ......`

Comment: Not clear what you want.  Please include sample table data for all tables including the output.

Comment: I have edit with a table look like, I need to make the table C, where they get data from table A and B. I've tried to concat but I don't get any result

Comment: Your updated request is not clear. There is `a.flag`. Does it have a meaning for the query? There are multiple records for a year in `b`, but only one per `code` in `c`. Which `B` records do you pick? What if `P1 flag=Y, P2 flag=N` or vice versa; which one wins?

Comment: And a general remark: You should come here and tell us your particular problem, but you merely say: "How to write this statement?". Where, however, are you stuck? Don't you know how to write a query where you join two tables without common data? Did you try anything? Or do you know how to write such query, but don't know how to insert based on a query result? Next time be more precise where your problem lies, please.

Comment: flag will only effect to my program, so if there's flag 'Y' of flag 'N', in my table C will keep the data as I post. I just show some of the field and data in my table to give some example.

Comment: This doesn't properly answer my question. If the flag for B = 2016 | P2 would be N instead of Y, how would that affect your result for C? Would you have two more records `EXE-2016 | N` and `IMP-2016 | Y`? Or would Y win over N? Or N over Y? Or does P1 always win over P2 or vice versa? (And if so, can there be P3, P4, ... - what about them?)

Comment: if in table B there's `2016|P1|Y` and `2016|P2|N` it will keep displaying 1 data of `EXE-2016 | Y` and only print 1 data. flag Y always over flag N. but if `P1` and `P2` are both flag N, then in table C it will display `EXE-2016 | N`. Did this statement answer? it will just like `distinct(year)`. Barbaros Ozhan answer is just like what i mean, but every `P1` and `P2` will be print so there's  two `EXE-2016`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to cross join records from two tables:

- each record from table A
- each year from table B with its MAX flag (i.e. 'Y' wins over 'N')

Then use `CREATE TABLE c AS <query>` in order to create a table C from the query result.

```
create table c as
select a.code || '-' || bb.year as status, bb.flag
from a
cross join
(
  select year, max(flag) as flag
  from b
  group by year
) bb;
```

(And maybe Barbaros Özhan is right and you actually want to create a view instead. Then use `create view c as <query>`.)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's better to create a `view` in such a way to record `sql` for later usage like a table :

```
create view tableC as
select code||' - '||year status, flag
from (
       select a.code, b.year, b.flag  from tableA a cross join tableB b       
     )
group by code, year, flag     
order by year, code;/

select * from tableC;/
```

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4a50b/1)

Comment: Don't write `inner join ... on 1=1`, because this is no inner join (where criteria from both tables must match), but a cross join. So write: `cross join tableB b`.

Comment: In your demo you use `insert into tableA values('EXE');`, what I need is they generate automatically from the other table. Because I have a lot of data in table A. Can you give another example? What you did looks like what I need

Answer (score -1):

```
create table C as
select A.code || '-' || B.year as status
from A, B
```

Comment: Even for a mere cross join, you shouldn't use a join syntax that was made redundant 25 years ago. Use proper ANSI joins: `from A cross join B`.

Comment: I guess nobody except my wife should say to me what I should do and what I shoudn't.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE table C as 
SELECT A.Code || '-' || B.Year AS 
STATUS , B.flag
FROM A,B
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of your solution. Otherwise the answer may be deleted.

Comment: Yes, what should I explain ?

Comment: I understood the result